# Help with declaration error in xcode

Tags: iphone

Hey guys, I'm pretty new to developing on the iPhone platform, and developing in general just as a heads up so please correct me if i screw anything up. So heres the problem: I'm trying to declare a property, I'm pretty sure the code is 100% correct yet xcode is declaring "No declaration of property 'window' found in the interface" and "No declaration of 'overlayViewController' found in the interface."
Here's the code.. I tried to use the code sample feature but it wasn't working for me..

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class OverlayViewController;

@interface OverlayViewTesterAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
 OverlayViewController *overlayViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet OverlayViewController *overlayViewController;


@end
```

Comment: Did you import your .h file in your .m implementation?

Answer (score 1):

you need two things in your .m file:

1. ## include "OverlayViewController.h'
2. @synthesize window;

Comment: #import "OverlayViewController.h" would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: -Eiko yes I did.

And both of those were included in the .m file except I had '#include "overlayViewController.h" in my code as "@synthesize overlayViewController so I tried your method with no luck